# How to 1). put a div , 2). render a component without Route inside <Routes> with React Router in v6 React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to put a div inside `<Routes>`  and also Render a `<Topbar />` and `<Sidebar />` component inside `<Routes>` without `<Route>` tag for them.

My code is as follows:-

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
        <Topbar />
        <div className="container">
          <Sidebar />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="users" element={<UserList />} />
        </div>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

I want to implement `<Topbar />` and `<Sidebar />` for all the routes.
But for an exception of login Page (`Topbar` and `Sidebar` should not be shown on the login page).
That's why I had put login Route at the top of `Topbar` and `Sidebar`.

The console is showing error as:

> Uncaught Error: [Topbar] is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`

How to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 only `Route` and `React.Fragment` components are valid children for the `Routes` component.

Use layout components to render the `Topbar` and `Sidebar` components along with an `Outlet` for nested routes for the routes you want to render these components.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <Topbar />
    <div className="container">
      <Sidebar />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  </>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="users" element={<UserList />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes like below,

you need to check whether user is logged in or not, if user logged in use Tobbar, Sidebar etc, otherwise just return login route

```
  const App = () => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false)


   return (
    <Router>
    <Routes>
   { isLogin ? <Topbar />
     <div className="container">
       <Sidebar />
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="users" element={<UserList />} />
    </div> : <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
  
  </Routes>
  </Router>
);
};
```

Comment: In doubt this work in reactrouter v6 because you still have children of Routes which aren't Route

Comment: it will work for sure

Comment: Children of Routes can only be Route. In your case if isLogin is true, TopBar and div are direct children of routes. Not too mention you forgot the fragment after the ternary operator.